# How to execute two repository functions in one Action

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, query-builder

I have a problem. I want to execute this

```
$events1 = $em->getRepository('AfishaBundle:Event')->getEvents($this->getCurrentRegion(),'2012-11-12');

//$event_repo->clear();`

$events2 = $em->getRepository('AfishaBundle:Event')->getEvents($this->getCurrentRegion(),'2012-11-13');

foreach($events2 as $event){
            die(var_dump($event->getSeanses()->toArray()));
        }
```

But result return with first date = "2012-11-12"
when I not use  `$event_repo->clear();`

That's ok but I have a problem with **Twig** rendering. 
Can I execute this without `clear()` method ? If I can't, please comment.

For sake of completeness, this is `getEvents()` code:

```
 public function getEvents($region, $date){

    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
            ->select('e,s')
            ->from('AfishaBundle:Event', 'e')
            ->leftJoin('e.seanses', 's')
            ->andWhere('s.date = :date')
            ->andWhere('s.region = :region')
            ->setParameter('region', $region)
            ->setParameter('date',$date)
    ;

     return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This is the relation between `Event` and `EventSeans`:

```
  /**
* @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="EventSeans",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"},
 *    mappedBy="event"
 *  )
 *  @ORM\OrderBy({"time"= "ASC"})
 */
protected $seanses;
```

Finally, this is date field in `EventSeans` entity

```
/**
 *  @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
protected $date;
```

Comment: Are you asking a permission or do you want to solve such a specific problem?

Comment: i want to solve my problem.
the second query return reuslt with date = '2012-11-12'

why?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't posted the full function `getEvents()`, but only the `QueryBuilde`r part. I don't know if $date is still a `string` or it is parsed as a `DateTime`!

Comment: After query builder part I return a result "getquery-> getresult". $date is a still , not parsed.

Comment: Maybe I've not been so clear! You have to post the full code, or finding the "error" will not be easy! We are programmer, not magician. :)

Comment: sorry :) i`m updated first post

Comment: Well, I have to ask you another thing! Do you get always the same result from `getEvents()` when you pass to that function two different dates? Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, i get the same result from getEvents();
result return with EventSeanses with date '2012-11-12' in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, consider that it's really hard to understand what you are asking for! I understood that when you pass two different dates to the `getEvents()` function you always get the same result.

It seems that the code you currently posted is ok, but you are going to do is not to select the `Event` entities with the `getEvents()` function.

If you ready the query from you QueryBuilder, you are selecting the `EventSeans` entities such that the $region and $date are the one provided by you! But you are nor selecting the `Event` entities nor involving the relationship between `Event` and `EventSeans` entities.

Maybe with more details and a better explanation of your problem one could helps.

---

**EDIT**
I think you should not select both `Event` and `EventSeanses`, since you can get all the `EventSeanses` objects from the `Event` entity once you retrieve the `Event` from repo. But I suggest to select all the `EventSeanses` such that the criteria are satisfied, and then to get the associated `Event` object directly from the `EventSeanses` object. Clean and easy.

```
public function getEventSeanses($region, $date){    
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
            ->select('s')
            ->from('AfishaBundle:EventSeanses', 's')
            ->andWhere("s.date = ':date'")
            ->andWhere('s.region = :region')
            ->setParameter('region', $region)
            ->setParameter('date',$date)
    ;

     return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Notice that in SQL you should put strings (like a date) like follows `'date'` and not simply `date`.

Then, in your controller you should do as follows:

```
$events = array();
$region=...
$date=....//year-month-day
$eventseansesList =   $em->getRepository('AfishaBundle:EventSeanses')->getEventSeanses($region,$date);
foreach($eventseansesList as $es){
  $events[] $es->getEvent(); // this function retrieve the Event associated to the EventSeanses
}
```

PS: You order `$seanses` by "time" in `Event` and not by "date", That's strange!

Comment: Well, you can add details in your questions, not change content everytime one found a problem.